# SSH from MacBook to Windows 10 server not working anymore after upgrading OpenSSH on the server?

Tags: windows-10, ssh, openssh

I have uninstalled OpenSSH client and server on my Windows 10 server, and then reinstalled them.

Now it has `OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2`, which are slightly higher versions than previously (I think it had OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.0p1).

However, now I cannot use SSH to connect to this Windows server on my MacBook.

```
(base) xxx@yyy ~ % ssh uid@aaa-bbb
ssh: connect to host aaa-bbb port 22: Operation timed out

(base) xxx@yyy ~ % ping uid@aaa-bbb
ping: cannot resolve uid@aaa-bbb: Unknown host
```

I can SSH to other servers on my MacBook; I can also ssh to another server on this Windows 10 server.

Is this because some OpenSSH version incompatibility issue between my MacBook (`OpenSSH_9.0p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6`) and the Windows server (`OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2`)?

More importantly, how can I fix this?

Comment: Answer me some more questions please. 1. On your Macbook, are you running Windows or MacOS? 2. Are you using a SSH config file to store your SSH locations on the Macbook? 3. Give us the version string of the ssh client on the macbook (`ssh -V`).

Comment: Maybe when you uninstalled openssh the Windows Firewall removed the exception/open-port? I'd check the firewall

Comment: The command `ping uid@aaa-bbb` should rather be written as `ping aaa-bbb`.

Comment: @MarekRost 1), MacOS; 2), Yes, I have the aaa-bbb location stored in the SSH config file; 3), OpenSSH_9.0p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6

Comment: @gregg Sorry but I am in "Windows Defender Firewall with Advanced Security" and I am looking at the Inbound Rules - how do I know exception/open-port is removed? If add a new rule and select "All local ports", would it be a security concern?

Comment: @harrymc yep I am getting `64 bytes from xxx: icmp_seq=0 ttl=123 time=86.406` ms msgs, until I ctrl+c

Comment: As a test, totally disable the Windows Defender Firewall.

Comment: @harrymc Once I turned off Microsoft Defender Firewall, I get `ssh: connect to host aaa-bbb port 22: Connection refused` when I try `ssh uid@aaa-bbb`

Comment: Try to [ping port 22](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/ping-specific-port).

Comment: 1)Verify the OpenSSH server (sshd) service is started: `Get-Service -Name ssh*`
2)If sshd service not started, get it going: `net start sshd`
https://github.com/powershell/win32-openssh/wiki
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_server_configuration

Comment: @gregg thanks a lot! I knew I missed something important. It works now! If you copy your comment to a new answer I will accept it. Though I still cannot use VS Code to remotely connect to the server (which is my original issue) but I will open a new question for it.

Comment: @Blue482 copied my last comment into an answer

Comment: @Blue482 [Deleted my answer](https://superuser.com/a/1759054/167207) since Gregg finally showed up and [posted their comment as an answer](https://superuser.com/a/1759107/167207). I’m not hogging someone else’s rep! Kudos, Gregg.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Verify the OpenSSH server (sshd) service is started:

   ```
    Get-Service -Name ssh*
   ```
2. If sshd service not started, get it going:

   ```
    net start sshd
   ```

More details here:

- https://github.com/powershell/win32-openssh/wiki
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_server_configuration

Summary of issue: OP's original question noted they couldn't ping the Windows 10 SSH server, but they were trying it with the @username notation at the end so the ping fail. After they pinged just the hostname/computer-name ping was working. Then they got 'connection refused' (unsure if after firewall disabled or before so they may need to still make a [firewall exception](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-firewall/create-an-inbound-port-rule), [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-firewall/best-practices-configuring)) which implies the SSH server is responding, but refusing. Turns out the SSH server dameon which is a Windows Service in this case wasn't started which eventually fixed the issue.

Comment: Kudos for posting your comment as an actual answer!

Answer (score 2):

I would check your dns first, if you can not ping (assume you have tried pinging correctly as per harrymc suggestion).

Do you know the IP address of the server you are connecting to, if you can ping the IP directly but not the name, then check the contents of `/etc/resolv.conf` (I believe this is correct for Macs, I am sure someone will correct if not)

You can also try and install bind with `brew install bind` then run

Using the default name servers
`dig aaa-bbb`

If the server is using a public domain then:

```
dig aaa-bbb @8.8.8.8
```

or

```
dig aaa-bbb @4.2.2.4
```

8.8.8.8 and 4.2.2.4 are public DNS servers.

If it is not a public domain, replace the `@8.8.8.8` with one of your internally dns servers.

As a last resort if you can ping the IP, but not the name, edit `/etc/hosts` with the name and IP.

```
echo <ip address of server> aaa-bbb >> /etc/hosts
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Open the Windows Task Manager and verify that the sshd.exe process is running. If it's not then something is probably wrong with its configuration file. Check the error log.
2. Open cmd and type `netstat -ano | find "22"`. Check that the server is indeed listening on port 22. Check the PID (right most column) and verify using Task Manager that it's indeed the sshd.exe process.
3. Connect to the server via IP address rather than host name to rule out possible DNS issues.
4. Temporarily disable Windows Firewall. If you're able to connect then you will need to edit or add a rule that allows SSH connections, since leaving the firewall switched off permanently is a security risk.
5. If nothing else works try using Putty to connect (A mac version is available from brew or MacPorts) to check whether indeed there is a compatibility issue - but I seriously doubt that.